# Trim Padding From ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, amazon-s3, stream, arrays

I'm working with Amazon S3 and would like to upload an InputStream (which requires counting the number of bytes I'm sending).

```
public static boolean uploadDataTo(String bucketName, String key, String fileName, InputStream stream) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1];

    try {
        while (stream.read(buffer) != -1) { // copy from stream to buffer
            out.write(buffer); // copy from buffer to byte array
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        UtilityFunctionsObject.writeLogException(null, e);
    }

    byte[] result = out.toByteArray(); // we needed all that just for length
    int bytes = result.length;
    IO.close(out);
    InputStream uploadStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(result);

    ....

}
```

I was told copying a byte at a time is highly inefficient (obvious for large files). I can't make it more because it will add padding to the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, which I can't strip out. I can strip it out from `result`, but how can I do it safely? If I use an 8KB buffer, can I just strip out the right most `buffer[i] == 0`? Or is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Using Java 7 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: There is no 'padding'. The problem here is that you are *writing* junk, by not including the 'count' parameter in the call to `write()`.

Comment: @EJP I fixed my issue now, but I don't think I was writing unexplained junk. The byte buffer would fill up as large as the InputStream allowed, while all other values in the array were set to 0 (default Java variable value, I believe). Thus, I would get text, followed by a million `NUL` or '\0', is that not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
int read = 0;
while ((read = stream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

`stream.read()` returns the number of bytes that have been written into `buffer`. You can pass this information to the `len` parameter of `out.write()`. So you make sure that you write only the bytes you have read from the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jakarta Commons [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) to copy from the input stream to the byte array stream in a single step. It will use an efficient buffer, and not write any excess bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want efficiency you could process the file as you read it.  I would replace `uploadStream` with `stream` and remove the rest of the code.

If you need some buffering you can do this

```
 InputStream uploadStream = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
```

the default buffer size is 8 KB.

If you want the length use File.length();

```
 long length = new File(fileName).length();
```

Comment: I tried that, AMZ library logged in capital letters a warning that you shouldn't really do this. So I am trying the safer way (also, this way is optimized by AMZ's library, can be multithreaded apparently).

Comment: @jsn  I can tell you that copying the file first is far, far worse.  It is much slower, more code and is much more likely to break for large files.

Comment: I'm might be misunderstanding, but there is no file that I am copying over to S3. It is all data from memory (InputStream from StringBuffer). What I'm doing is that I'm reading the entire stream to get number of bytes, and then recreating it and passing it to S3 with the number of bytes (for optimization; I could pass it just the stream, but then it gives me that warning).